# Migration to sandbox not happening

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sandbox

I am sandboxing an existing application, and for some reasons the migration does not seem to work, although I am following exactly what is specified in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html). In summary, here is what I am doing:

1. I have removed the existing container (in ~/Library/Containers/com.mycompany.myapp);
2. I have created the `container-migration.plist` in the Resources group;
3. I want to migrate a single file, in `~/Application Support`: I have tried to specify the file, and the enclosing folder, neither worked. Here is the migration plist that I am using (I have just changed the application name), with the folder:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
           <key>Move</key>
           <array>
               <string>${ApplicationSupport}/myapp</string>
           </array>
       </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
4. When I start the application, the new container is created, and a blank file is created but no migration is performed.

The file that I am trying to migrate is a CoreData SQLite store. The data model has not changed so there is no data migration involved, I am simply trying to move the CoreData store to the sandboxed container.

I guess I am missing something very obvious, as I can't find anything useful around, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `/myapp` be the name of the file/directory you want to migrate?

Comment: It is, the directory is "~/Library/Application Support/myapp". The plist above matches this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after posting the question I noticed this error in the system log:

```
13/11/2012 4:59:59.026 PM sandboxd[55845]: ([55835]) myapp(55835) deny file-read-data /Volumes/Mac_HD/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-hfgnivbvxutfvcxjmyntrenofdsh/Build/Products/Debug no receipt verif
```

I tried to copy the application to my Desktop before running it, and from there it works correctly. I do not understand why from the build folder the migration does not work, but this is sufficient to solve my problem.

Hopefully this will avoid somebody else to waste their time.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. I've been trying to figure out why my migration manifest has been doing nothing for the past 3 hours, and it was because of the build folder thing.